# Proof that a function is not surjective

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that this function is not surjective.Is this the right approach?

Define a function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(x)= \frac{2x-1}{x+1}$

After solving for $x$ and letting $y=f(x)$ I get $x= \frac{y+1}{2-y}$

Proof:

In order for $f$ to be surjective $\forall y \in \mathbb{R}, \exists x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=y$.

Since there does not exist $y=2 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=y$. $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: It seems correct to me.

Comment: The wording of the last line can be improved to:$\;$Since there does not exist $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=2$, $f$ is not surjective.

Comment: There's a problem, not so much with your proof, but with the definition of $\ f\ $.  The notation $\ f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ $ implies that the domain of $\ f\ $ is the whole of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $, but the expression $\ \frac{2x-1}{x+1}\ $is not defined at $\ x=-1\ $.  Strictly speaking, therefore, you cam't know that $\ f\ $ is not surjective unless you're told that $\ f(-1)\ne 2\ $.  On the other hand if the definition of $\ f\ $ had had $\ f:\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ $ instead, then there would be  no problem at all with your proof.